# Net Core: Publish Deploy Database with Dot Net Command Line

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, sql-server-2016

Is there a way to publish and deploy SQL Server databases from .Net Core Applications Folders using the Dot Net Command line? Was trying to see if possible , without sqlpackage.exe. Our company only allows Microsoft Nuget Packages, no custom third party nuget packages for this.

Maybe something eg:

```
dot net publish sqlproject localhost dbname
or dot net publish sqlproject.dacpac
```

Comment: You could use an official [Microsoft NuGet Dacfx package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DACFx/150.4505.1-preview) but would need to invoke it programmatically or via a PowerShell script. Also note the listed dependency and that it is in preview.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "deploy SQL Server databases"... are you talking about table & schema changes?  Data migrations?  Something else?  Have you looked at EF Core?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet